# 'stripspaces' makes integer from pointer without cast

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <ctype.h>  
#define STRING_LEN 500         
void stripspaces(char, char, char);


int main(void)  
{  
   char string[STRING_LEN];         
   char *p1 = string;          
   char *p2 = string;

   printf("Enter a string of up to %d characters:\n", STRING_LEN);  
   while((*p1++ = getchar()) != '\n') ; 

  stripspaces(string, *p1, *p2); 

  getch();  
  return 0;
}  
void stripspaces (char s, char *x1, char *x2){ 
   *x1 = '\0';                 
   x1 = s;                
   while(*x1 != '\0')    
   {  
     if(ispunct(*x1) || isspace(*x1))  
     {                    
       ++x1;              
       continue;  
     }  
     else  
       *x2++ = *x1++;   
   }  
   *x2 = '\0';          
   printf("\nWith the spaces removed, the string is now:\n%s\n", s);  
}
```

This code is bringing up the following error at the '`stripspaces`' function; "passing arg 1 of '`stripspaces`' makes integer from pointer without a cast" any help would be excellent.

In case it is not obvious from the code, the program should take in a string and remove all the spaces from it. The function has to remain although I know I can do it without the function.

Comment: You are interchangeably using `char` and `char *`. They aren't the same you know.

Comment: Don't you need to include `conio.h` for `getch`/`_getch`?

Comment: @Bojan Komazec, assuming you're not being sarcastic, why are you asking me? Do you really think I'd know? that's why I'm asking this question, because I don't have a clue.

Comment: @Thomas Don't get me wrong, I just wanted to help. `getch` on Windows is declared in `conio.h` (`curses.h` on Unix) and I noticed it was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prototype and function definition don't match:

```
void stripspaces(char, char, char);
```

vs.

```
void stripspaces (char s, char *x1, char *x2)
```

You should change the prototype to

```
void stripspaces(char, char*, char*);
```

And in order to make them both work, you should use

```
void stripspaces(char*, char*, char*);
```

and

```
void stripspaces (char *s, char *x1, char *x2)
```

.

For easier copy & paste, you can use parameter names in the prototype as well.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers above are telling you that your function declaration is wrong. Also you are dereferencing pointers when passing them to the function.

```
stripspaces(string, *p1, *p2);
```

This turns the call into (char*, char, char) which is not right and will not behave as you expect it to. It is also the source of the particular compiler error you are seeing. The compiler is trying to fit the string(char*) into a char, and thus making an "integer from pointer without cast" since char is basically an 1 byte integer.

Correcting the function declaration would be step one, you want to pass all pointers or you won't be able to manipulate the string.

Fix the declaration and then call the function like this.

```
stripspaces(string, p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the first argument from `char s` (single character) to `char *s` (pointer)